# How to use inline if statement

Tags: python

am fairly new to programming and i don't get how the inline if statement works.
i wanna do something like this:

```
tries = 0
Numbers = "Hello world"
for x in Numbers: (print(( f"found{x}" if x == "o" else None)), tries += 1 if x != "o" else 0)
```

so if it does find x which is "o" it prints it else it adds 1 to tries, i tried multiple ways of doing it but none of them worked ( i know my code looks very weird and all but i'm still learning so please no bullying!)

i tried many things none of them worked

Comment: You do *not* want anything like this, no. That is entirely unreadable.

Comment: Working with inline code in this condiions will make you fall on a pitfall, considering that python requires indentation to compile itself.

Comment: The "inline if statement" is an *expression*, not a statement. Its purpose is to choose between two *values*, not between statement blocks. `if x == "o": print(f"found{x}") else: tries += 1` is way more readable than your mess.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, this is not a good idea.
It's hard to read and doesn't make anything better.

---

Just to provide an actual answer to your question:

```
tries = 0
Numbers = "Hello world"
for x in Numbers: tries += 0 if x == "o" and not print(f"found{x}") else 1
```

When x is "o", then the second part of the condition will be checked, which checks if the `print` statement is not true. `print` should return `None` so `not None` becomes true, which means the condition is true and `0` will be added to `tries`. If x is not "o" then the condition is false and 1 will be added.